# Is it possible to ORDER depending on which WHERE condition succeeded?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table called `temp` which contains int attributes `a` and `b`:

```sql
create table temp (id int primary key, a int, b int);
insert into temp values(1, 1, 1);
insert into temp values(2, -1, 1);
insert into temp values(3, -1, -1);
```

I need to sort some `SELECT` results depending on which one `WHERE` condition succeeded. A primitive but not working example:

```sql
select *, priority from temp where (
    case 
        when a > 0 and b > 0 then 1 
        when a > 0 or b > 0 then 2 
        else 0 
    end
    as priority
) > 0 order by priority asc
```

It says something like "if `a` and `b` are both positive then this tuple will be one of the firstest. If at least one of the attributes is positive then this tuple comes after first ones. Else don't select the tuple"

So is it possible to save a `CASE` result to use it in `ORDER`? Or maybe there are workarounds without having to check the conditions twice in both `WHERE` and `ORDER` or making possibly expensive `UNION`?

Comment: Hi, "priority from temp" what is priority ? An Alias you wish to name your selected value ?

Comment: Hi. A `CASE`'s result

Answer (score 1):

Please explain what is wrong with this(if anything is)?

```
select * 
from temp 
order by case 
         when a > 0 and b > 0 then 1 
         when a > 0 or b > 0 then 2 
         else 0 
         end
```

Just use your case when then end logic in order by clause(without using "priority" alias).

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5cd3b5e6d17c6f04913ff328593811df)

Then this should be ok for you:

```
select * --to select all
from temp --from your table
where (a > 0 or b > 0) --where a or b is bigger than 0 because this is the same as your case when then end example
order by case --I have used your logic for order by clause
        when a > 0 and b > 0 then 1 
        when a > 0 or b > 0 then 2 
        else 0 
    end
```

[Here is a second demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8b531b7662671bf951ece5277e7b4d8c)

And this is a third option suggested by OP:

```
select *
from temp 
where (a > 0 or b > 0)
order by case 
        when a > 0 and b > 0 then 0
        else 1
    end
```

[Here is a third demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bd072d181d1aad138cde2eb3c47554f8)

Comment: It also selects tuples which have both `a` and `b` negative

Comment: It works, but still uses almost the same checks in `WHERE` and `ORDER` which, as mentioned in the question, I would prefer to avoid if possible. Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: By the way @VBoka you gave me an idea with the answer. We can avoid using duplicates in these checks just by removing this `OR` condition in `ORDER`. `WHERE` already got rid of `a < 0 and b < 0` results. So the only check we need to do in `ORDER` is `a > 0 and b > 0` and give its results the higher priority in ordering. That way we have only 2 checks without duplicates. You were close, gave you +1. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: I can't be sure if this approach will help in other conditions, so I won't mark this as a solution yet. Maybe someone have a better approach

Comment: Hello @Lizurt I believe this will not give you the same results. Correct me if I am wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=83d88731c60f8e1ec82c8ca53c50b809

Comment: Hi @VBoka. It gives same results, you just set ELSE block higher priority in ordering, but actually need lower since you order using ASC. So you need to swap WHEN and ELSE result numbers. I edited your dbfiddle

Comment: Hi @Lizurt, got it. Updated my answer...

Comment: Oops I miss typed with > and < in that example. It gave same results though. Updated your dbfiddld again

Comment: Share with me the dbfiddle so I can see it :)

Comment: Ah, thought you see my changes. Here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=665eb23d90d3fd8ece4c143bfe60e762